# Find first parent and add class via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

HTML:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-10 views-row-even views-row-last">    
  <div class="sonuc">        
    <span>text1</span>  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-11 views-row-even views-row-last">    
  <div class="sonuc">        
    <span>text2</span>  
  </div>
```

JS:

```
if ($(".sonuc").has(":contains('text1')").length) {
  $('.sonuc').parent().addClass('hobi')
}
```

Its work but add `hobi` class all parent divs. But I want add only text1's parent div. How can I fix it?

Comment: his code itself is adding hobi to both the divs but the problem is it is adding to both.so his check in if contion is not proper i think.

Comment: @Bariskonat can you clarify whether you need to match all instances that have the text `text1` and only that text, or if you also need to match on for example `text11` and `text1 abc` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use the code without `if` statement, that is completely unnecessary at this context.

```
$(".sonuc").has("span:contains('text1')").parent().addClass('hobi')
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use `:contains` selector along with required div selector:

```
 $('.views-row:contains(text1)').addClass('hobi');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bLn7q3d/)**

Comment: A little issue with `:contains` you end up with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/wph0vwjk/)

Comment: that is not the DOM OP is having. this solution suits for the currently provided DOM.

Answer (score 15):

jquery selector [**:contains()**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) match any element that contains the string. I suggest to use [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
$(".sonuc span").filter(function() {
  return this.innerText === "text1";
}).parents("div.views-row").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-10 views-row-even views-row-last">
  <div class="sonuc">
    <span>text1</span> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-11 views-row-even views-row-last">
  <div class="sonuc">
    <span>text2</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-11 views-row-even views-row-last">
    <div class="sonuc">
      <span>text11</span> 
    </div>
```

Comment: this is what i was about to post.

Comment: this is what OP should use.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the right element in one filter:

```
$(".sonuc:contains('text1')").parent().addClass('hobi');
```

Or if you really mean the first parent, then just use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$(".sonuc:eq(0)").parent().addClass('hobi');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find parent of `sonuc` but add class to `sonuc` only

```
if ($(".sonuc").has(":contains('text1')").length) {
  $('.sonuc').addClass('hobi')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `first()` in your jquery

```js
if ($(".sonuc").has(":contains('text1')").length) {
  $('.sonuc').first().parent().addClass('hobi')
}
```

```css
.hobi{
color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-10 views-row-even views-row-last">    
  <div class="sonuc">        
    <span>text1</span>  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-11 views-row-even views-row-last">    
  <div class="sonuc">        
    <span>text2</span>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just combine what you allready got.

```
$('.sonuc').has(":contains('text1')").parent().addClass('hobi');
```

maybe its not a good idea to test on text, it might changes...

to get the first element of a set of elements you can:

```
$('.sonuc').eq(0).parent().addClass('hobi');
```

or

```
$('.sonuc:eq(0)').parent().addClass('hobi');
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more simple straight forward way without using `:contains`, `.filter()` is,

```
$('.sonuc > span:first').parent().addClass('hobi');
```

It selects the first direct descendant span under `.sonuc` class and then by using `.parent()` selects it parent and adds the class '.hobi' in it.

**[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/6bLn7q3d/1/)**

---

```js
$('.sonuc > span:first').parent().addClass('hobi');
```

```css
.hobi {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-10 views-row-even views-row-last">
  <div class="sonuc"> <span>text1</span>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-11 views-row-even views-row-last">
  <div class="sonuc"> <span>text2</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```